# When to use double quotes and single quotes php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$act = "1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pp_ta WHERE Lic = '".$lic."' And WHERE active= '".$act."'");
```

Error 0You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE active= '1'' at line 1

Im thinking it has to do with quotes. Ive been tryng for 7 hours to figure it out..Any ideas?

Comment: 7 hours on 1 string? You have an error in your SQL syntax, nothing to do with quotes.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE cola = 'value' and colb = 'value'` Where did you get the idea to add in a `WHERE` clause in the middle of an `AND` statement.

Comment: That did it!!!!!!! I went through a BUNCH of different version of this statement..at one time I removed the second where..thank  u xor!!

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use where two times in one query. 
try this

```
$act = "1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pp_ta WHERE Lic = '".$lic."' And active= '".$act."'");
```